# Is it really possible to flatten the data returned from a graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, graphql, graphql-js

I  have a data structure like below

```js
{
  "MyAsset": {
    "Code": "Cod123",
    "MyAssetLocation": [{
        "Location": {
          "LocationName": "Location 1"
        }
      },{
        "Location": {
          "LocationName": "Location 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanted to write a graphql query against the entity MyAsset in such a way that it should return the data like below.

First record

```
{code:"Cod123",MyAssetLocation.Location:"Location 1"}
```

Second Record

```
{code:"Cod123",MyAssetLocation.Location:"Location 2"}
```

Basically I wanted to flatten the result by duplicating MyAsset details with `MyAssetLocation.Location` Items.

Comment: how Elaticsearch is used here?

Comment: @Narendra In fact I am using a transpiler in my application which converts the graphql query into elastic which will fetch the data from my mongoDB.

Comment: @Joseph I did the rollback the mine changes

Comment: GraphQL does not support applying arbitrary transformations to the shape of the response. You would have to either change the schema server-side to reflect the desired shape of the response, or else transform the data after it is fetched client-side.

Comment: @DanielRearden Got a link on graphql lodash which I am not sure can be used here. Here is the link https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash

Comment: `graphql-lodash` still just applies the transformation client-side. The `@_` directive is stripped out before the query is sent to the server. You might find it to be a helpful abstraction, but if you're using a client like Apollo, it may also add unnecessary complexity to your app.

Comment: @DanielRearden If the @_ are striped out before sending the query to server how the data filtering happens as part of the query? By the way I didn't see any option to flatten the data like I wanted using that library.

Comment: Read their README for details on how the library works. It basically just keeps track of what transformations should be applied based on the directive and then applies them when the response is returned from the server. Either way, my point is there is no way to do what you're trying to do through the query itself. If you can't or don't want to change your schema, then flatten the data inside your client app.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for the valuable comments.